# Gridview with a drop down list in one column is not displaying said drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with one column that is meant to display a drop down list. I have set it up exactly like numerous examples I've seen online but the drop down list doesn't appear.

Here is the asp for my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvDetails" OnPreRender="DrawDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvDetails_RowDataBound" width="100%" runat="server">

  <columns>

  <asp:BoundField
      HeaderText="Description"
      ShowHeader="true"
      DataField="Description">
      <itemStyle width="20%"/>
    </asp:BoundField>

    ...

   <asp:TemplateField
      HeaderText="Status"
      ShowHeader="true"
      >
      <ItemStyle width="16%"/>
      <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:DropDownList 
          id="ddlStatus" 
          Style="width:100%" 
          runat="server"
          >
          <asp:ListItem value="1">Closed</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem value="2">Open</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem value="3">Approved</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

  </columns>
```

I'm not sure if you need to see the code relating to the gridview (OnPreRender and RowDataBound)?
Let me know and i'll edit this if you do. Its not doing anything out of the ordinary though.

Why is this drop down list not appearing?

**Edit:** I've added some code in the RowDataBound event of the gridview, that outputs to my log if it can find the control. It can find the control fine, just the drop down list is not appearing.

**Edit 2:** As requested, here is the RowDataBound event:

```
protected void gvDetail_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
  GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)gv.DataSource;

  int col=0;
  switch(gvr.RowType)
  {
       case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
          col=0;
          foreach(DataControlFieldCell cell in gvr.Cells)
          {
              switch(col)
              {
                 case 0: 
                    cell.CssClass += " purpleBG center"; break;
                 case 5: 
                    cell.CssClass += " operatorEntryBG center"; break;
                 default: 
                    cell.CssClass += " tableCell"; break;
              }
              ++col;
          }
          break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does your gridview populate with info, so you see rows with a 'Description' header but you just don't see the dropdown column?

Comment: Show us your on RowDataBound Please ? and do you bind your grid to a datasource which is not empty ?

Comment: Yes, all the data is there. Only the drop down list doesn't appear.
In the RowDataBound event of the gridview I can event find the control and output its value :/

Comment: Siraj, I've edited the OP with the RowDataBound event. It is not doing anything out of the ordinary. And yes, the datasource is fine, it returns many rows which all display fine except for the drop down column.

Comment: And if you put in a label or literal or something with text value on either side of the dropdownlist they appear as well? Just trying to isolate if it's a formatting thing or an actual problem with the DDL.

Comment: What if one of your css classes sets display to none, for your control or a parent container ?

Comment: Skeleton, I can output text in the cell fine. I an even output the selected item's text correctly. The drop down still does not appear though.

Comment: Siraj, I tried removing the css but it had no effect.

Comment: Try removing the width 100% from the ddl. Actually a DDL doesn't have a style attribute surely, try removing that entirely.